# How to open a file whose name is stored in a pandas cell, manipulate the contents and store in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

## Dataframe Example

| index | fileName | startline | endline |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 293104.java | 30 | 40 |
| 1 | 288951.java | 183 | 247 |
| 2 | 2378709.java | 98 | 117 |

### Goal

I want to open and read the contents of the file in fileName, and extract the lines in the range created by the values in the startline and endline columns.

I then want to store that in a new column called snippet.

#### Example of snippet creation logic

```
def snippetMaker(fileName, startLine, endLine):
     file = open(fileName,'r').read()
     snippet = file.split('\n')[startLine:endLine]
     cleanSnippet = str(snippet).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace(',',' ')
     return cleanSnippet
```

#### Current approach

I have seen that map() is often used in functions like that shown above (given that the function can accept iterable arguments and returns a list) then set equal to a dataframe column like below.

```
df['snippet']= snippetMaker(df['fileName'],df['startLine'],df['endLine'])
```

I am having trouble reconfiguring the above snippetMaker function to work in such a way.

#### Other details

I do not want to use Iterrows, the dataframe contains over 8m rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use `apply`, which will apply the function to each row, you write the function to take a single row of the dataframe and then you can use dot notation to access the columns in the function.

```
def snippetMaker(row):
     file = open(row.fileName,'r').read()
     snippet = file.split('\n')[row.startLine:row.endLine]
     cleanSnippet = str(snippet).replace('[','').replace(']','').replace(',',' ')
     return cleanSnippet 

df['snippet'] = df.apply(snippetMaker, axis=1)
```